# Combine multiple POSTs and adding it to table

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, post

Here is my code to add multiple types to table. I want to combine areas, location, types and add them in the table at once. I think this just wont work `if(!empty($_POST['types'] && $_POST[''] && $_POST[''] )` Thanks!

```
if(!empty($_POST['types'])) {   
    $values = array();
    foreach($_POST['types'] as $typ_id) {
        $values[] = sprintf('(%d, %d)', $station_id, $typ_id);
    }

    $query = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO station_typ_tab
          (station_id, typ_id, area_id, location_id)
          VALUES ' .
          implode(',', $values);
          mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
   }
```

EDIT: here is part of code for types[] and same is for areas and location

```
<td>Types:<br/> <small>CTRL + click to set multiple pollutants</em></small>
   </td>
   <td>
   <?php
    $query = 'SELECT typ_id, typ FROM typ_tab ORDER BY typ ASC';
    $result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo '<select multiple name="types[]">';
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
           if (isset($station_typ[$row['typ_id']])) {
              echo '<option value="' . $row['typ_id'] . '"
              selected="selected">';
              } else {
                  echo '<option value="' . $row['typ_id'] .'">'; 
              }
              echo $row['typ'] . '</option>';
           }
           echo '</selected>';
        } else {
          echo '<p><strong>Databaza je prazdna... <a href="edit_pollutant.php">Enter database</a></strong></p>';
        }
        mysql_free_result($result);
```

how to combine $_POST for types, location and areas if they comes from different selecting input. something like `if(!empty($_POST['types'] && $_POST['areas'] && $_POST['location']) ){ $values = array(); foreach( NEW VARIABLE as $typ_id && area_id &&location_id) { $values[] = sprintf('(%d, %d, %d, %d)', $station_id, $typ_id, area_id, location_id);` if it is possible to do it like this

Comment: what is the value of $_POST['types'] ?

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: how to combine $_POST for types, location and areas if they comes from different selecting input. something like `if(!empty($_POST['types'] && $_POST['areas'] && $_POST['location']) ){   
    $values = array();
     foreach( NEW VARIABLE  as $typ_id && area_id &&location_id) {
        $values[] = sprintf('(%d, %d, %d, %d)', $station_id, $typ_id, area_id, location_id);`
    if it is possible to do it like this

Comment: You're mixing queries to database and outputting of HTML in the same PHP script, not surprising that you are confused.

Comment: Please can you explain your answer more??

Comment: Yes, I am confused, and yes now I know that foreach will work only for two arrays. So is there option how to combine this 3 posts in one variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to combine in IF try to use

```
if((!empty($_POST['types'])) && (!empty($_POST['area'])) && (!$_POST['location'])));
```